# How to count the string occurrences in python

Tags: python, list

I have this file

```
10, 44.66.44.55 , AD, AC , 112
10, 44.66.54.55 , AD, AC , 112
10, 44.66.44.55 , AD, AC , 112
50, 44.66.64.55 , AD, AC , 112
10, 44.66.54.55 , AD, AC , 112
10, 44.66.44.55 , AD, AC , 112
```

I want to add the column1 with same ip address. i want the output like

```
30, 44.66.44.55 , AD, AC , 112
20, 44.66.54.55 , AD, AC , 112
50, 44.66.64.55 , AD, AC , 112
```

I want to do in python

I tried

```
import re
import collections

a = collections.Counter()
with open("temp.txt", "r") as f:
   for line in f.readlines():
         list = line.split()
     a[list[1]] += int(list[0])
         print list[1]
```

Comment: Try using a `collections.Counter`.

Comment: @nneonneo thanks , i forgot that , i will try that

Comment: @nneonneo , i tried the above and it gave the error , invalid literal

Answer (score 1):

You may use the itertools.groupby solution, which is ideal in this case

```
>>> with open("test.csv") as fin:
    grouped_lines = groupby(sorted((e.split(',') for e in fin), key = itemgetter(1)), key = itemgetter(1))


>>> for k, v in grouped_lines:
    lines = list(v)
    lines[0][0] = sum(int(e[0]) for e in lines)
    print lines[0]


[30, ' 44.66.44.55 ', ' AD', ' AC ', ' 112\n']
[20, ' 44.66.54.55 ', ' AD', ' AC ', ' 112\n']
[50, ' 44.66.64.55 ', ' AD', ' AC ', ' 112\n']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split on `,` not on white spaces

try this

`list = line.split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

There is a `collections.Counter` module. It returns a dictionary of of `{'word': numberTimes}` http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 0):

Although @Abhijit's answer is shorter,
Try this, it also works.

After processing the file data, I store the data in a dictionary. This data is then manipulated when needed.
Your data is the values in the dict.

```
all_ips = {}

f = open('Test2.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

for line in lines:
    ip = line.split(',')[1]

    props = line.split(',')
    props[0] = int(props[0])

    if ip not in all_ips:
        all_ips[ip] = props
    else:
        all_ips[ip][0] += props[0]

for ip in all_ips:
    print all_ips[ip]
```